# Choose highest value according to a statement or condition in R

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame and categorial values whereby the condition or statement below is true ~ values are ordered  : condition|statement  = a>b>d>c>0>z>y>x>w>q>r>n>m>t

```
df<- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                measure1 = c('a', 'd', 'q'),
                measure2 =c('c', '0', 'n'),
                measure3 = c('z', 'r' ,'t'))
```

I want to create columne measure4 whereby the input is the highest value for an observation from the columns according to the statement. In here, measure4 would be c('a', 'd', 'q') for ID 1,2,3 respectively.

Comment: I did not understand *highest value* in this context.

Comment: a is larger than b, b is larger than d and so on according to the statement mentioned above @Marcio Rodrigues

Comment: Do you have an ordered factor with levels as shown above saved already? If yes, convert all measures to factor and take max from each row

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal. Yes, I had created an ordered factor vector. But I am unsure how to mutate measure4 while taking into account the ordered levels. Would you be able to write out the synthax, please ?  
```
status<- c("a", "b", "d", "c", "0", "z", "y", "x", "w", "q", "r", "n", "m", "t")%>%
  factor(levels = c("a", "b", "d", "c", "0", "z", "y", "x", "w", "q", "r", "n", "m", "t"), ordered = T)%>%
  fct_rev

df.new<- df%>% rowwise()%>%
  mutate(measure4 = max(measure1, measure2, measure3))
```
This is what I am doing but I am not getting the desired outcome. Excuse my clumsy coding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ordered` -

```
library(dplyr)
order_set <- c("t", "m", "n", "r", "q", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "c", "d", "b", "a")


df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('measure'), ordered, order_set)) %>%
  mutate(measure4 = do.call(pmax, select(., starts_with('measure'))))

#  ID measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
#1  1        a        c        z        a
#2  2        d        0        r        d
#3  3        q        n        t        q
```

Answer (score 0):

A non factor approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                measure1 = c('a', 'd', 'q'),
                measure2 =c('c', '0', 'n'),
                measure3 = c('z', 'r' ,'t'))


hierarchy <- c("a", "b", "d", "c", "0", "z", "y", "x", "w", "q", "r", "n", "m", "t")

orders <- seq(length(hierarchy), 1) %>%
            set_names(hierarchy)


highest_col <- select(df, starts_with('measure')) %>%
                map(~ map_dbl(.x, ~max(orders[.x]))) %>%
                map(~ max(.x)) %>%
                reduce(c) %>%
                which.max() 
    


mutate(df, measure4 = df[, highest_col + 1])
#>   ID measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
#> 1  1        a        c        z        a
#> 2  2        d        0        r        d
#> 3  3        q        n        t        q
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Using `factor()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                measure1 = c('a', 'd', 'q'),
                measure2 = c('c', '0', 'n'),
                measure3 = c('z', 'r' ,'t'))

lvls <- c("a", "b", "d", "c", "0", "z", "y", "x", "w", "q", "r", "n", "m", "t") 

lvls <- map(length(lvls):1, ~lvls[[.x]]) #reverse order

mutate(df, measure4 = select(df, starts_with('measure')) %>%
                        map(~factor(.x, levels = lvls, ordered = TRUE) %>% max()) %>% 
                        {df[, which.max(.) + 1]} #add one to account for the first column with id's
)
#>   ID measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
#> 1  1        a        c        z        a
#> 2  2        d        0        r        d
#> 3  3        q        n        t        q
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>